# Integrate login with LinkedIn in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

I am Integrating the Login with LinkedIn in symfony framework using Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client.After Updating composer When I run the code it gives me error like

```
'Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn' not found.
```

Please Help.

Comment: which version do you have of the library and which version do you use of sf2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for correctly load, you can use the slash before the class:

```
    $linkedIn=new \Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn('app_id', 'app_secret');
```

Or add the use statement:

```
...
use Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn;


$linkedIn=new LinkedIn('app_id', 'app_secret');
```

More info about Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

PS: Depends of the version of the library you use the namespace about Happyr could be HappyR

Hope this help